# Unbale to install packages in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

```
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package xrdp (--configure):
 installed xrdp package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up ca-certificates (20210119~20.04.2) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package ca-certificates (--configure):
 installed ca-certificates package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libpam-systemd:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libpam-systemd:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of snapd:
 snapd depends on ca-certificates; however:
  Package ca-certificates is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package snapd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udisks2:
 udisks2 depends on libpam-systemd; however:
  Package libpam-systemd:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package udisks2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on ca-certificates; however:
  Package ca-certificates is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xrdp
 ca-certificates
 libpam-systemd:amd64
 snapd
 udisks2
 google-chrome-stable
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to explain what you did to get that error, as well as exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Giving us terminal output with no context or background is not very helpful in identifying the problem you are experiencing. You should always include details and context including all of the steps it takes to reproduce the error.  In addition to providing more details, you should also edit your question and include the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Edit your question, and tell what else is happening. Such as telling the context of what has happened.